# Open .net windows form after event finishes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.5

I'm having a Windows Mobile CE application written in C# with .Net CF.

Consider i have 2 forms in my application:

1. List of objects (has a listview)
2. Details page (should appear when something is selected in previous listview)

Currently i'm attaching callback to listview's `SelectedIndexChanged` event, and open a new form there.

New form opens okay (in the midde of the event callback), but when i close the form(`this.Close()`), then the list page isn't clickable first time, after the first click UI is interactable again.

Also the the `ListViewItem` clicked at first step doesn't get selected(blue background).

Here's a short (12s) video showing this problem: http://take.ms/urkme
As you see from the video, after coming back from details screen, refresh button doesn't click on the first click..

I'm showing the details form like so:

```
private void listView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (new FormDetails()).ShowDialog();
}
```

Is there any way to show the details form after event finishes, or am i doing it completely wrong?

**PS!** Tried the same with a Button and it's click event, then all worked nicely..

Answer (score 1):

As I know `ListView`'s `SelectedIndexChanged` event fired twice on almost case not like `Button`'s `Click` event which fired once, this maybe what cause that weird interaction. Maybe try changing to `ItemSelectionChanged` event as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3230530/3413552).

Comment: That makes sense, one for deselecting and one for new selection.. Will try that out!

Comment: Also to mention i'm working with Compact Framework 3.5, so ItemSelectionChanged its not available, but will try if you hunch is correct :)

Comment: I have not tried with Compact Framework 3.5, but you can use `if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)` with `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Comment: Your hunch was somewhat correct. When nothing is selected then it fires once. When something is selected then it fires twice(deselect old selection and the select new). But my problem happens even it gets called once.. But i didnt account for event firing twice so upvote is still valid :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by using the `SelectedIndexChanged` event. When you select an item in your list you'll set the `SelectedIndex`, if you select the same item again the index won't be changed so you'll never call the event.

You could use the `Click` event to trigger the wanted response.

Here is an example:

```
private void listView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var firstSelectedItem = listView1.SelectedItems[0]; //This is your selected item.
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: I'll try the click event, but the problem is not re-selecting, it is that the item never gets selected i guess.. Minus with the click is also that i dont know if an item or emoty space in listview was clicked. When i click on empty space i't shouldn't fire..

Comment: Oh, I get it now. You should have a parent shell for both forms or you could declare the ListView as the the `MdiParent` of the detail form.

Answer (score 0):

When you use ShowDialog() you open a form in modal mode. All further processing of following code will not take place until the modal form is closed or returns a DialogResult.
Better use a modeless form using .Show().

```
private void listView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (new FormDetails()).Show(); //will not stop processing of events in mainForm
}
```

If the new FormDetails is finished, it can use a simple Hide or Close to bring up the main form to foreground.
Remember that the main form is still there and will not wait for the FormDetails being closed (as it is a modeless dialog).