# ListView ItemSelectionChanged fires more often than expected

Tags: winforms, listview, c++-cli

This isn't the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229498/listview-itemselectionchanged-fires-twice) which boiled down to the "deselect" and "select" events.  What I see is not two fires per selection change but *four*.  Simplified code:

```
System::Void myclass::handleSelectionChange(Object ^ sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs ^ args) {
    if(myListView->SelectedIndices->Count == 1) { // This also serves to filter out "deselect" events (MultiSelect = false)
        if(myUnsavedChanges && myListView->SelectedIndices[0] != myPreviousSelection) { // No need for this bit if the newly-selected item is the "dirty" item
            Windows::Forms::DialogResult response = MessageBox::Show("Save your changes?", "Unsaved changes", MessageBoxButtons::YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon::Warning);
            if(response == Windows::Forms::DialogResult::Cancel) {
                // re-select the edited item
                myListView->SelectedIndices->Clear();
                myListView->SelectedIndices->Add(myPreviousSelection);
            } else if(response == Windows::Forms::DialogResult::Yes) {
                // save the changes, don't reselect the edited item
            } else if(response == Windows::Forms::DialogResult::No) {
                // let the changes be lost
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've got a lot of debugging messages clearly showing me the following course of events when I click an item after making a change in the form:

1. `handleSelectionChange` enters (and exits) with the deselection of the "dirty" item
2. `handleSelectionChange` enters with the selection of the clicked item
3. The `MessageBox` appears and I click "Cancel"
4. `handleSelectionChange` enters (and exits) with the deselection of the clicked item
5. `handleSelectionChange` enters with the selection of the "dirty" item

...then it gets interesting:

6. `handleSelectionChange` enters (and exits) with the deselection of the "dirty" item *again*
7. `handleSelectionChange` enters with the selection of the clicked item *again*
8. The `MessageBox` appears and I click "Cancel" *again*
9. `handleSelectionChange` enters (and exits) with the deselection of the clicked item *again*
10. `handleSelectionChange` enters with the selection of the "dirty" item *again*

Then everything settles down and the ListView shows the previously-selected item (the "dirty" item) selected.

More curiously, if I have a breakpoint anywhere within the delegate, the problem doesn't occur (only events 1-5 take place).

I've even tried doing a BeginInvoke to change the selection so that the programmatic selection change occurs after the delegate exits, but no no avail.  The behavior is still the same.  If I eliminate the MessageBox and just make the code take the "Cancel" path, the behavior includes everything up to (including) step 6, and I wind up with nothing selected.  So it's not completely the MessageBox's fault, though that affects the behavior.

Why is this happening?  Why doesn't the sequence of events stop after step 5?  Where are the additional ItemSelectionChanged events coming from?