# ListView SelectedIndexChanged items getting inserted twice

Tags: c#, listview, vsto, selectedindexchanged

I have a list of clauses in my database and a listview in my custom pane in VSTO.
When I select or drag and drop a list item, it gets copied twice. I found this answer.
 [Listview ItemSelectionChanged fires twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229498/listview-itemselectionchanged-fires-twice)

But I dont have a isSelected method for my EventArgs e.
Below is my code, please help me out, I want the data/text to be copied only once.

```
private void clauseList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection col = clauseList.SelectedItems;

    string temp = clauseList.FocusedItem.Text;
    clauseList.DoDragDrop(temp, DragDropEffects.Move);

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection currentSelection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range range = currentSelection.Range;    
    currentSelection.TypeText(temp);
    currentSelection.TypeParagraph();
    clslst(select);
}

public void clslst(object s)
{
    DataAccess data = new DataAccess();
    List<ClauseDetails> details = new List<ClauseDetails>();
    details.AddRange(data.ClausesRelated(s));

    string FromtextFromDoc;
    FromtextFromDoc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Text;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
    List<string> clslist = new List<string>();
    string aa = "";
    int f = 0;

    string tempindex = "";
    foreach (Paragraph paragraph in docs.Paragraphs)
    {
        Style style = paragraph.get_Style() as Style;
        string styleName = style.NameLocal;
        //var sty = style.Font;
        //fontstyle = sty.Name;
        //fontsize = sty.Size;
        if (styleName.Equals("Heading 1"))
        {
            f += 1;
            if (f == 2)
            {
                tempindex = aa;
                f = 0;
                clslist.Add(tempindex);
                aa = "";
            }
        }
        if (f > 0)
        {
            aa += paragraph.Range.Text;
        }
    }
    clslist.Add(aa);
    List<string> ClausesNotPresent = new List<string>();
    List<string> ClausesPresent = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < clslist.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < details.Count; j++)
        {
            if (clslist[i].Contains(details[j].clausetitle) || clslist[i].Contains(details[j].clause))
            {
                ClausesPresent.Add(details[j].clausetitle + "\n" + details[j].clause);
            }
        }
    }
    List<string> test = new List<string>();

    for (int z = 0; z < details.Count; z++)
    {
        test.Add(details[z].clausetitle + "\n" + details[z].clause);
    }
    if (ClausesPresent.Count < details.Count)
    {
        ClausesNotPresent.AddRange(test.Except(ClausesPresent));
    }
    for(int m=0;m<ClausesNotPresent.Count;m++)
    {
        ClausesNotPresent[m] = "\n"+ ClausesNotPresent[m];
    }

    clauseList.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < ClausesNotPresent.Count; i++)
    {
        clauseList.Items.Add(ClausesNotPresent[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Than don't use `EventArgs e` and instead use the specific `EventArgs` your `ListView` provides.

Comment: I am using the default event the listView automatically generated it.

Comment: What ListView are you using? Can you give me the namespace of it?

Comment: I am using System.Windows.Forms.ListView

Comment: Try to use the `ItemSelectionChanged Event` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.itemselectionchanged